# OnPause is called immediately after Oncreate, OnResume

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I got a weird problem in my Application, In My Activity `OnPause()` is called immediately after `OnCreate()` and `OnResume()`. I have some functions to be performed in `OnPause()`, but  I don't know why this is happening. In My Log it showing as:

```
05-14 13:40:09.916: E/TestActivity(840): onCreate()
05-14 13:40:09.936: E/TestActivity(840): onResume()
**05-14 13:40:09.956: E/TestActivity(840): onPause()**
05-14 13:40:09.956: E/TestActivity(840): onResume()
```

**EDIT**

```
    public class PreTestActivity extends Activity{

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "iPTPrefsFile";
    private static final String TAG = "PreTestActivity";
    SharedPreferences settings;

        static final int HEART_RATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
        static final int BLOOD_PRESSURE_DIALOG_ID = 1;
        static final int RESPIRATORY_RATE_ID = 2;
        static final int O2_SATURATION_DIALOG_ID = 3;

    Button testActionNextButton,testActionBackButton;
    EditText Heart_Rate_EditText,Blood_Pressure_EditText,Respiratory_Rate_EditText,O2_Saturation_EditText;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pre_test);
         Log.e(TAG, "onCreate()=");
        settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

        Heart_Rate_EditText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Heart_Rate_EditText);
        Blood_Pressure_EditText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Blood_Pressure_EditText);
        Respiratory_Rate_EditText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Respiratory_Rate_EditText);
        O2_Saturation_EditText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.O2_Saturation_EditText);

        testActionNextButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.testActionNextButton);
        testActionNextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!Heart_Rate_EditText.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")&&!Blood_Pressure_EditText.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")
                   &&!Respiratory_Rate_EditText.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")&&!O2_Saturation_EditText.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                Log.d(TAG,"Heart_Rate_EditText="+Heart_Rate_EditText.getText().toString());
                Log.d(TAG,"Blood_Pressure_EditText="+Blood_Pressure_EditText.getText().toString());
                Log.d(TAG,"Respiratory_Rate_EditText="+Respiratory_Rate_EditText.getText().toString());
                Log.d(TAG,"O2_Saturation_EditText="+O2_Saturation_EditText.getText().toString());


                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

                float PreHeartRate=Float.parseFloat(Heart_Rate_EditText.getText().toString());
                float PreBloodPressure=Float.parseFloat(Blood_Pressure_EditText.getText().toString());
                float PreRepositoryRate=Float.parseFloat(Respiratory_Rate_EditText.getText().toString());
                float PreO2saturation=Float.parseFloat(O2_Saturation_EditText.getText().toString());

                editor.putFloat("preHeartRate", PreHeartRate);
                editor.putFloat("preBloodPressure", PreBloodPressure);
                editor.putFloat("preRepositoryRate", PreRepositoryRate);
                editor.putFloat("preO2saturation", PreO2saturation);
                editor.commit();
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
                if(validateForm()) {
                       Intent PreTestActivityIntent = new Intent(getParent(), TimerActivity.class);
                       BergBalanceScaleActivity parentActivity = (BergBalanceScaleActivity)getParent();
                       parentActivity.replaceContentView("PreTestActivity", PreTestActivityIntent);

                }

                }
        });
        testActionBackButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.testActionBackButton);
        testActionBackButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //finish();
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //isRecord=1;
        Log.e(TAG, "onPause()=");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        //isRecord=1;
        Log.e(TAG, "onStop()=");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.e(TAG, "onResume()=");
        if(settings.getFloat("preHeartRate", 0)==0.0 && settings.getFloat("preBloodPressure", 0)==0.0 && settings.getFloat("preRepositoryRate", 0)==0.0 && settings.getFloat("preO2saturation", 0)==0.0){
            Heart_Rate_EditText.setText("");
            Blood_Pressure_EditText.setText("");
            Respiratory_Rate_EditText.setText("");
            O2_Saturation_EditText.setText("");
            }else{

                //if(isRecord==1){
                 Heart_Rate_EditText.setText(""+settings.getFloat("preHeartRate", 0));
                 Blood_Pressure_EditText.setText(""+settings.getFloat("preBloodPressure", 0));
                 Respiratory_Rate_EditText.setText(""+settings.getFloat("preRepositoryRate", 0));
                 O2_Saturation_EditText.setText(""+settings.getFloat("preO2saturation", 0));
                //}
            }
     }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getParent());
        AlertDialog dialog;
        switch(id) {

            case HEART_RATE_DIALOG_ID:
                builder.setMessage("Pleas, enter  Heart Rate.")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    }
                });
                dialog = builder.create();
                break;
            case BLOOD_PRESSURE_DIALOG_ID:
                builder.setMessage("Please enter  Blood Pressure.")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                            }
                });
                dialog = builder.create();
                break;
            case RESPIRATORY_RATE_ID:
                builder.setMessage("Please enter  Respiratory rate.")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                            }
                        });
                dialog = builder.create();
                break;
            case O2_SATURATION_DIALOG_ID:
                builder.setMessage("Please enter  O2 Saturation.")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                            }
                        });
                dialog = builder.create();
                break;

            default:
                dialog = null;
        }
        return dialog;
    }
    boolean validateForm() {
        boolean result = true;
        if("".equals(Heart_Rate_EditText.getText().toString())) {
            showDialog(HEART_RATE_DIALOG_ID);
            result = false;
        } else if("".equals(Blood_Pressure_EditText.getText().toString())) {
            showDialog(BLOOD_PRESSURE_DIALOG_ID);
            result = false;
        } else if("".equals(Respiratory_Rate_EditText.getText().toString())) {
            showDialog(RESPIRATORY_RATE_ID);
            result = false;
        } else if("".equals(O2_Saturation_EditText.getText().toString())) {
            showDialog(O2_SATURATION_DIALOG_ID);
            result = false;
        } 
        return result;
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me in this.

Comment: How do you launch this activity?

Comment: where it is calling..tell about ur code ?

Comment: Some code samples would really help..

Comment: i have added some code.. Please check it out

Comment: My guess is, somewhere you are tinkering the UI the way you shouldn't, for example starting another Activity, or something that makes your current one to stop, only for a moment, but it happens. It probably happens in the `if` or the `else` part of your `onResume`, where you left out the snippets.

Comment: Are you starting this activity via an intent and have defined the function onNewIntent(Intent intent) in your activity? In that case, before the call to onNewIntent(), onPause() is called.

Comment: @hundeva I am not calling any stop or any UI effected methods in OnResume, Storing the edittext values in the shared preferences in else part

Comment: @vickey I am starting activity using new Intent only, but not calling OnNewIntent() in the activity..

Comment: You don't call onNewIntent(Intent intent). Android calls it for you if you've declared it in your activity.

Comment: @vickey I did not declare OnNewIntent method in my Activity..

Comment: Can you post the full activity code?

Comment: @wolverine try moving non-essential code (i.e not setContentView or shared prefs) in onCreate() to onStart() instead and see what happens

Comment: @o0rebelious0o I tried.. Same thing happening as before..

Comment: @Wolverine is the validateForm() method being called?  In my experience showing a dialog causes onPause to be called.  Try commenting out the showDialog() calls in validateForm() and see if that stops onPause() being imediately being called. Also, try stepwise debugging to work out execution flow or, add a Log.i() at the beginning of each method showDialog(), validateForm() etc to work out what order the methods are being called. Post the new logcat order back to the question